# how to capture from file lines that start with single bracket and end with single bracket

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

how to capture from file lines that start with single bracket and end with single bracket

I try this

```
cat file  | grep "\[*\]"
```

but not sure if this syntax give the good results

example of file:

```
cat file

WATCHER::
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
```

expected output

```
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a dot? `grep "\[.*\]"`

Comment: Also `-x` to match the entire line: `grep -x '\[.*\]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep '^\[.*\]$' file
```

- `^` match the start of the line
- `\[` match the opening bracket
- `.*` match any character, any amount (zero or more)
- `\]` match the closing bracket
- `$` match the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

1) no need to `cat file` before `grep`
2) use a more accurate regexp pattern `[[^]]\+\]$`

```
$ grep '\[[^]]\+\]$' file
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Source file with more complicated input data:**

```
$ cat file2
WATCHER::
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
begin [20, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21] end
begin2 [30, 35, 34, 33,
 32, 31] end2
begin3 [40, 41] middle3 [50, 51, 52] end3
end of file
$
```

**1. Simple**

```
$ grep '\[[^]]*\]' file2
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
begin [20, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21] end
begin3 [40, 41] middle3 [50, 51, 52] end3
$
```

**2. Advanced**

```
$ cat file2|grep '\[[^[]*\]'|sed 's/^[^[]*\[/[/g;s/][^]]*$/]/g;s/][^[]*\[/] [/g'
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
[20, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21]
[40, 41] [50, 51, 52]
$
```

**3. Advanced multi-line**

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/^[^[]*\[/[/g;s/][^]]*$/]/g;s/\n//g;s/][^[]*\[/]\n[/g;' file2
[1006, 1005, 1004, 1003, 1002, 1001]
[20, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21]
[30, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31]
[40, 41]
[50, 51, 52]
$
```